# Write java loop with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am automating UI flow using Webdriver and Java. Need help in the following:

Clicking a link, verifying the title, clicking browser back button - these steps are repeated for number of links in the content. I am using page object design and all the objects are in different class. My code is:

```java
objectBase.clickLink1();
titleVeri(pageTitle1);
driver.navigate().back();
objectBase.clickLink2();
titleVeri(pageTitle2);
driver.navigate().back();
```

`objectBase` is the name of the object where I kept all my page objects. `clickLink1` and `clickLink2` are methods on page objects class which does clicking on links. `titleVeri` is utility method for verifying the title.

What I need is construct this inside loop as I have more this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please rephrase your actual question? I'm having a hard time identifying what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a map for this, make a method clickLink(key) in objectBase

then do something like

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new TreeMap();
myMap.put("1",pageTitle1);
myMap.put("2",pageTitle2);

for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : myMap.entrySet()){
    objectBase.clickLink(entry.getKey());
    titleVeri(entry.getValue());
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not strictly possible.  The reason is that you cannot have a pointer to a function.

However, you said that you are using the Page objects pattern.  Rather than using the `clickLink1()` function, do you have a function that returns `link1()`?  That way you could use a Map (like BevynQ said).

```
Map<WebElement, String> linksAndTitles = new HashMap();
linksAndTitles.put(page.getHomePageLink(), "Home");
linksAndTitles.put(page.getUserPageLink(), "Contact Details");
...and so on for each of the different links...

for (WebElement link: linksAndTitles.keySet()){
    link.click();
    titleVeri(linksAndTitles.get(link));
    driver.navigate().back();
}
```

As a side note...if one of those links is the Logout link...that has to be tested seperatly.

Furthermore...I really don't recommend this test...it's likely just a waste of time.  On each of your pages, in your `isLoaded()` function, you should test the title.  That way, whenever you call `page.get()`, the title will be automatically tested, and it isn't part of your test.